# Total derivative of poison

Tags: derivatives

I’m studying Adiabatic pressure change by reading text book and encounter this equation

$(1)\:\:\:\:\:\:PV^γ=constant $

Total Derivative of $(1)$ will be
$∂P/P=-γ∂V/V $ 
 Can somebody explain process of this equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the differential
$$
V^{\gamma}dP+P\gamma V^{\gamma-1}dV=0
$$
and divide by $PV^{\gamma}$.

Answer (score 0):

$PV^\gamma=c \\ 
\Rightarrow P = cV^{-\gamma} \\ 
\displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {dP}{dV} = -\gamma c V^{-\gamma-1} \\
\displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {dP}{dV} = - \gamma \frac P V$

Comment: Thank u so much!!